# Array Count is 0 after adding an element?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using the code below to add an Object of my `Platform` class (basic storage class, subclass of `NSObject`) to an `NSMutableArray`.
But the `NSLog` statement outputs `0`.

How can this happen?

```
Platform *platform = [Platform platformWithLabel:label identifier:identfier];

[self.platforms addObject:platform];

NSLog(@"%i", [self.platforms count]);
```

This is the creation method of `Platform`:

```
+(Platform *)platformWithLabel:(NSString *)label identifier:(int)identifier
{
    Platform *platform = [[Platform alloc] init];

    platform.label = label;
    platform.identifier = identifier;

    return platform;
}
```

I'm using ARC. This is how I declare my `platforms` array:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *platforms;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are forgetting to initialize the NSMutableArray itself.  Check and make sure you're doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're not initializing your `self.platforms` array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to initializing the NSMutableArray :)

```
platforms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```